# Keyboard navigation in WPF grid using arrow keys

Tags: wpf, grid, keyboard-navigation

I have a grid which contains a number of textboxes. I want to move from one text box to other using up/down/left/right keys.
I have tried setting KeyBoardNavigation.DirectionNavigation property on the grid but it doesn't work. However the Tab navigation is working fine.
Any suggestion please.

Comment: Seems mad to take away the right and left arrow key function from a text box.  The user will now have to use the mouse to position the cursor?

Comment: Yes they have to use mouse for that. The functionality will be similar to excel. Any idea how to implement it??

Comment: See my answer below - just edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in my comment: this is a strange thing to *want* to do - however, I think the easiest way is to make yourself a special jumpy textbox which overrides the preview keydown event to action the focus change.

```
public class JumpyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);

        if (e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down)
            MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous));

        if (e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Right)
            MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
    }
}
```

The XAML then works like a normal textbox:

```
<local:JumpyTextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="field 1" />
<local:JumpyTextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="field 2" />
```

You can then contain the tab navigation inside your grid with the 'special' textboxes:

```
<Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
```